# htaccess does not redirect webpages without https

Tags: .htaccess

Im figuring out why when I try to access to https://legacy.dhnn.com/wip/ypf/ruta-nube/ypf-ruta-contado.html, with http instead of https, it wipes the subdomain "legacy"

I dont know much about redirections, but seems like .htaccess needs to be configured, but i dont know how, i did something, but it is not working

Also, i have a lot of websites inside folder "wip", and I dont want to create an htaccess file for each site, is that possible?

is this code right?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dhnn.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://legacy.dhnn.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://legacy.dhnn.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: The first step should be to find out where the actual problem comes from. A subdomain does not somehow magically get stripped from a request. Something must cause that. And if you don't identify what that cause is, how do you expect that you can change that behavior then?

Comment: In short: you have another redirection rule in place that is responsible for redirecting to the base URL. That is what you need to fix. But we cannot help with that if you don't show that existing rule.